# Why "No module named tensorflow" when I installed tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I use sudo `pip install tensorflow-1.7.0rc0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` in centos7,python version is `2.7.14`

[image]

I get successfully installed tensorflow,but when I run `import tensorflow as tf`,I get a error:No module named tensorflow

[image]

what should I do? thanks!

Comment: Do _not_ install python packages with `sudo`. Use [virtualenv](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)s.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you best method for installing pyhton packages is to use a virtual environment. For a simple way to do this you can install [Minicaonda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) for `linux x86` using the following command:

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash ./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Then it is worth reading the [instructions on using conda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-conda), to set up a virtual environment called `tensorflow`. But the basic command should be:

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6 tensorflow
```

provided you want to use tensorflow with python3.6. Then activate your tensorflow conda environment:

```
source activate tensorflow
```

and you should be able to import tensorflow without issue.

```
(tensorflow) user@machine:~$ python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>>
```